# how to bind xml file data to combobox in codebehind without Linq in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

iam trying to bind an xml file into a combobox in my application.
I have successfully achieved with xaml approach with the help of the examples available in the net. But i need it to be done in codebehind and without Linq.

xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="">
    <appSettings>
      <LATLONG Latitude="17.396296" Longitude="78.448558">
    </LATLONG>
       <SDH> 
           <Signal Name = "None"/>
           <Signal Name = "Time"/>
           <Signal Name = "Mode"/>  
        </SDH>
      </appSettings>
</Configuration>
```

this is the xml file and i need "None", "Time", "Mode" to be combined to cb1 (Combobox).

```
 <Grid.Resources>
 <XmlDataProvider x:Key="AppConfig" 
  Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/AppConfiguration.xml" 
   XPath="Configuration"/>
 /Grid.Resources>


 ComboBox x:Name="cb1" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource>ResourceKey=AppConfig},XPath=./appSettings/SDHData/Signal}"  
                  DisplayMemberPath="@Name" 
                  SelectedValuePath="@Name"
                  Grid.Row="0" 
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  Margin="10" 
                  IsEditable="True" 
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectionChanged="cb1_SelectionChanged" />
```

i need this action to be completed in code behind without LINQ as iam not using database for communication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is indeed possible. but wondering what is the connection between DB and LINQ that prevents you from using LINQ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't have any experience in LINQ, so iam just trying to use normal C# code for binding the data. do i need to provide the xml example?

Comment: got your concern, xml example would be appreciated. but at the same time you can get your hands dirty with linq too.

Comment: ok sure i will try that. actually i faced some errors in including it so i stopped using it.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
    using (Stream res = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/AppConfiguration.xml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
    {
        XElement xe = XElement.Load(res);
        cb1.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)xe.XPathEvaluate("./appSettings/SDH/Signal/@Name");
        cb1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    }
```

above example is based on your XML. as xml has `SDH` where as the code has `SDHData` element. you can choose based on what you need